# Sql server using a built int function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a SP that uses the substring function inside a stored procedure where I use the column name as input. However when I run

```
exec sp_addCountySchoolDistrict N'table', N'districtCountySchoolCode'
```

It uses the `'districtCountySchoolCode'` for the substring and not the value from the row...

For example

```
create table [dbo].[test] (districtCountySchoolCode nvarchar(100))
insert into dbo.test values ('1234567891234')
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_addCountySchoolDistrict
    @tableName nvarchar(100),
    @colName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);



SET @Sql=   N'alter table ' + replace(replace(quotename(@tableName),']',''),'[','') + 
               N' add countyCode as ''' + substring(@colName, 1,2) + N',
                      districtCode as ''' + substring(@colName, 3,5) + N',
                      schoolCode as ''' + substring(@colName, 8,7) + N';'
    select  @sql;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
GO
exec sp_addCountySchoolDistrict N'[dbo].[test]', N'districtCountySchoolCode'

select * from test_copy
```

[Coder Wall](http://rextester.com/HEKC53724)

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand your question....

Comment: When I run the SP it uses 'districtCountySchoolCode' for @colName instead of '1234567891234'

The actual query should be `alter table [dbo].[test]
 add countycode  as substring(districtCountySchoolCode, 1,2),
     districtCode as substring(districtCountySchoolCode, 3,5),
     schoolCode as substring(districtCountySchoolCode, 8,7)`

Comment: plus 1 for trying to provide a sample demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the substring in the literal part of the dynamic sql, like this:

```
 N' add countyCode as substring(''' + @colName+ N', 1,2) ,
```

Comment: That worked with a little tweaking:
`N'alter table ' + replace(replace(quotename(@tableName),']',''),'[','') + 
               N' add countyCode as substring(' + @colName + N', 1,2),
                      districtCode as substring(' + @colName + N', 3,5),
          schoolCode as substring(' + @colName + N', 8,7);'` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
exec sp_addCountySchoolDistrict N'[dbo].[test]', N'1234567891234'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you pass the "column name" as a string but your code nowhere selects the value from test table for the specified column. You have to perform a select statement first, to get the value and then use the value in the rest code.

This should work

```
create table [dbo].[test] (districtCountySchoolCode nvarchar(100))
insert into dbo.test values ('1234567891234')
go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_addCountySchoolDistrict
    @tableName nvarchar(100),
    @colName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @val nvarchar(100);
    declare @initialQuery nvarchar(100);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @initialQuery = 'SELECT @value=' + quotename(@colName) + ' FROM ' + replace(replace(quotename(@tableName),']',''),'[','')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @initialQuery, N'@value nvarchar(100) OUTPUT', @value=@val OUTPUT

SET @Sql=   N'alter table ' + replace(replace(quotename(@tableName),']',''),'[','') + 
               N' add countyCode as ''' + substring(@val, 1,2) + N''',
                      districtCode as ''' + substring(@val, 3,5) + N''',
                      schoolCode as ''' + substring(@val, 8,7) + N''';'
    select  @sql;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
GO
exec sp_addCountySchoolDistrict N'[dbo].[test]', N'districtCountySchoolCode'

select * from test
```

But you have to add a where condition i suppose if you have more than one values in `test` table.